# ASP.NET runs locally in Vis Web Dev but not on server - Type not defined

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I know this will seem like a dumb question but I'm just getting started in .NET from an old-school C mindset.

I created a program in MS Visual Web Developer 2010.  It has a form that simply launches a script that manipulates a database.  The project lives in several files and they are all inherited so they see each other and it accesses a MSSQL Express DB on one of our servers.

When I F5-Run the project locally on my PC it works fabulously.  When I copy it to a web-enabled (application) folder on the server it executes but almost my very first line of code fails with this error:

Type 'Able' is not defined.
  which is in some code like:

```
Namespace TTASync
Public Class Sync
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Sub btnBegin_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBegin.Click
        txtStatus.Text = "Running"
        txtOutput.Text = "BOO"
        Begin()
    End Sub

    'create the classes
    Public myAble As Able = New Able
```

Where btnBegin is the launch button in my web page.

As I said, it works great on the PC running locally in the ASP.NET Dev Server window but not on the server.  What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you port the .dll that contains the Able class into the /bin directory on the server?

Comment: The entire code is in a hand full of files in one namespace and one project.  I am using web dev express so there is no publish wizard.  I don't see a bin folder or dll's in the folder so the answer is no.  Does it compile that as needed since it's in the same project or am I missing a fundamental truth here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a dumb question.  I had started a web Project instead of a web Site and was just totally confused about the implications of each.  It's all sorted now but if anyone is reading this in the same situation find out which is which and see if you are doing the right one to start with.